# Retrieve a subset of data using ImportJSON custom function

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm using Trevor Lohrbeer's [`importjson()` custom function](http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json) to import some data from [this JSON source](http://www.pgatour.com/data/r/stats/current/102.json) into a Google Sheet.

I don't want all of the information provided; I specifically only want columns E, V, W, X, AA, AB, AC, AD.

I tried a few things before realizing I have no idea what I'm doing with this parameter:

```
=importjson("http://www.pgatour.com/data/r/stats/current/102.json","This","AndThis")
```

How can I modify this function to retrieve only the items mentioned above?

Comment: `importjson` is a custom function written by Trevor Lohrbeer and [documented here](http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily using the [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en), post-filtering the results of the `importjson()` call.:

```
=QUERY(importjson("http://www.pgatour.com/data/r/stats/current/102.json"),"select Col5, Col22, Col23, Col24, Col27, Col28, Col29, Col30")
```